# How to test CSS change in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jasmine

I'm testing an Angular directive which contains the following link function:

```
function link(scope, element) {
  var address = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
  address.on('click', function() {
    address.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
  });
}
```

Within my directive unit test I have the following spec:

```
it('should remove the blur effect when clicked', function() {
  var address = element.find('.blur');
  expect(address).toBeDefined();
  expect(address.length).toBe(1);
  address.triggerHandler('click');
  expect(address).toHaveCss({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
});
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error message:

```
Expected ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1 }), context: undefined, selector: '.blur' }) to have css Object({ -webkit-filter: 'none' })
```

Comment: try `expect(address[0])`

Comment: That changed the error to `Expected HTMLNode to have css Object({ -webkit-filter: 'none' })`.

Comment: can you try your code with another css property, like `display`?